# Human detection with webcam python openCV

Tags: python

I wanted to do a human detection with a webcam, but I cannot get pass this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-72d16e24e4b8> in <module>()
     33 
     34   ret, frame = cap.read()
---> 35   cv2.imshow( face_detector(frame))
     36   if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13: #13 is the Enter Key
     37     break

<ipython-input-6-72d16e24e4b8> in face_detector(img, size)
      7 def face_detector(img, size=0.5):
      8     # Convert image to grayscale
----> 9   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     10   faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
     11   if faces is ():

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Here is my code which error:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow( face_detector(frame))
```

Comment: Please extend your code to an example that is complete enough to be runnable and demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Here, I ask question with all code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341835/human-detection-opencv-on-google-colab

Answer (score 1):

I have already posted Answer on This question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279532/12059759

let me know if it will work!